# isql fials to connect with DSN, but can otherwise

Tags: sql-server, odbc, unixodbc, isql

I'm trying to connect to SQL server using `isql`, when I run --

> `isql -k -v "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;UID=user;PWD=password"`

-- it works, but when I use --

> `isql -k -v "DSN=TEST_DSN;UID=user;PWD=password"`

where `TEST_DSN` (in `/etc/odbc.ini`) is

```
[TEST_DSN]
Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Server=tcp:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,1433
```

It gives me the old `[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified`

The server IP is the same, the name of the driver is the same, the port is default (and is open, I checked), so what could it be about the use of DSN that makes it not work?

Comment: 1. Full content of `odbc.ini` may be necessary for analysis. 2. What are `$ODBCINI`, `$ODBCINSTINI`, `$ODBCSYSINI` environment variable settings? 3. `Server` values are quite different for your tests.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I tried to add some tracing at the top of my odbc.ini but did not put it into [ODBC] header which broke things -_-

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer for others having this issue. Please provide much more detail, or delete your question.